# Order of effects on hit

Tags: dnd-4e

The Invoker power "Rain of Blood" (Divine Power) says:

> Hit: 2d6 + Wisdom modifier damage, and the target gains vulnerable 5 to all damage until the end of your next turn.

Does the vulnerable 5 happen before or after you roll damage? To make the question more general, when a damage and effect happen on a hit, which happens first?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As a general rule: follow the order it is worded out. This stands for sentences within a block and for the order of blocks too (sometimes an effect occurs before the attacks, for example).

So, in the Rain of Blood case, the target takes 2d6 + Wis damage, *and then* it takes vulnerability.